# R - generating GEV distributed random numbers

Tags: r

I have question regarding the understanding of the GEV distribution and R. I'm trying to generate a random GEV sample using

```
library(EnvStats)
xi <- -0.7
mu <- 1.9
sigma <- 2.5

sample <- rgevd(1000, location = mu, scale = sigma, shape = xi)

print(mu)
print(sigma)
print(xi)
print(mu-sigma/xi)

head(sample,10)
```

leading to the output

```
[1] 1.9
[1] 2.5
[1] -0.7
[1] 5.471429
 [1]  8.50568681  0.45874684  3.06160317  0.04819771  4.43052845  1.96018146
 [7] -0.47317852 16.44478624  4.08909365 21.74838553
```

In my understanding if xi!=0 (true in my example) the pdf of the GEV is bounded by mu-sigma/xi (either to the left or to the right depending on the sign of xi - in my example to the right, so -inf < x <= 5.471429 = mu-sigma/xi). Why is the generated sample not bounded?

Thanks.

Comment: In your example the sample is bounded *to the left* of `mu + sigma/xi` (note the plus sign) since the shape parameter is negative. This is the 3rd formula in `help('rgevd')`. Run `all(sample >= mu + sigma/xi)` to see it.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. Some definitions flip the sign of xi - that caused the confusion here.